# Using Django's "truncatechars" to get last n characters of a word

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

While I was learning Django Templates, I came to know that we can use Django's built in template's truncatechars function to get first n characters of a world like this;

Here, data = Stackoverflow.com

```
{{ data|truncatechars:9 }} # It would print "Stackover.."
```

But what should I do If I need last 9 characters of a word like '..rflow.com'

Is there built in function in django template which can give me the inverse of truncatechars:9 ?

Comment: Haven't tested this on strings, but [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) might be able to do the trick.  Try `{{ data|slice:"9:" }}`.

Comment: Using {{ data|slice:"9:" }} ,it is skipping  9 characters from the beginning of a word then prints, Not getting as wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve those things like this...

```
{% block body %}
     <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <div><strong>Output-1 =</strong> {{a|truncatechars:9}}</div>  <!-- Using Only (truncatechars) -->
        <div><strong>Output-2 =</strong> {{a|slice:'9:'}}</div>  <!-- Using string (slicing) -->
        <div><strong>Output-3 =</strong> {{a|slice:'::-1'|truncatechars:9|slice:'::-1'}}</div> <!-- Using string (slicing + truncatechars) -->

     </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

#### Browser Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you dear, It did the work as expected;